# Tomcat 7 Service Inactive

Tags: centos7, tomcat7

Very new to Linux and currently tasked to install tomcat 7 in centos 7 os.

I followed the instruction in [How To Install Apache Tomcat 7 on CentOS 7 via Yum](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-centos-7-via-yum). Everything seems to be ok and did not get any errors but as soon as I run

```
sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

It shows that the tomcat.service is Active: Inactive (Dead).

I opened the catalina.out to see error messages but it is not showing any error. Would appreciate any help to nudge me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend removing the admin package once you've got it running. It's a pretty big security risk.

What *does* /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out tell you?
What does journalctl -u tomcat7 give you? java -version?
Is something else already listening on port 8080?

Finally, have you tried undoing the customizations from the walkthrough? If the defaults work it could be a fat finger or other misconfiguration.